# ASP.Net core change field from default id to custom id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm building an asp.net core application using the database first method with EF core. I have a Users table with a few fields just for this example. The primary key is on the UserId field, In my UsersModel i have set the [Key] attribute to UserId.

Id = int

UserId = uniqueidentifier

UserName = nchar

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UserDetails(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || _context.UsersView == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var usersModel = await _context.UsersView
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (usersModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(usersModel);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<a asp-action="EditUser" class="bi bi-pencil" style="font-size:larger;" data-toggle="Tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"></a>
```

This all works great, but I dont want to use the Id column. I have changed my controller method to accept userId and have changed the html to post the model.UserId but the parameter in my controller is always empty. I did some research on Ef core and the primary key etc, and it seems that Ef core will use the Id field by default. Is there any way to change this ? as it would be better practice to reference the UserId.

Many thanks
AJ

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to set the customerID as the key and the Id not as the key?

Comment: Hi Brando, sorry if my explanation was a bit vague. Thats exactly what I'm trying to do, if I change the Id parameter to customerId in the controller and pass it in to the method, I get an error that the key is an int and cannot accept Guid, Entity Framework seems to force the Id column by default and I'm looking for a way to override that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I went down a rabbit hole of primary keys and db indexes and was looking in the wrong place. All I had to do was change the html tag to send the correct id through.

asp-route-CustomerId="@item.CustomerId"

All part of the learning curve I suppose